# Bullet points and curly braces

Tags: formatting

I am trying to create a bit of text, where I have four bullet points, the latter three of which have a curly brace on the right } , and a line of text adjacent to the curly brace.

So far, I have managed to get the curly brace next to the three lines of text, but can not get bullet points, and the first line of text is not lined up with the corresponding three.

If this makes sense, can someone please advise me on how to fix it?

The code I have is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,graphicx,tabularx}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Riemann Sum\\
\[\left\ \begin{array}{l l l}
\text{Trapezoidal Rule}\\
\text{Simpson's 1/3 Rule}\\
\text{Simpson's 3/8 Rule}\\
\end{array} \right\} \right.\ - \text{Newton Cotes formulae of different degrees}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the layout you currently have, you should use an `itemize` the way it's intended:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Riemann Sum

  \item
  Trapezoidal Rule

  \item
  Simpson's 1/3 Rule
    $\smash{\left.\rule{0pt}{.5\dimexpr3\baselineskip+2\itemsep+2\parskip}\right\}
      \text{Newton Cotes formulae of different degrees}}$

  \item
  Simpson's 3/8 Rule
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Due to the positioning of the contents, a `\right\}` brace is inserted alongside the middle item, `\smash`ed to avoid any vertical disturbance.

Consider reading up on [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/5764)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, and thank you for the link.

Comment: Fortunately there are odd number of items embraced. lol.

Comment: @Sigur: Hence my reference to "due to the positioning of the contents". Of course, adjustments are possible for an even number of items.