# Bullet points and curly braces - Beamer

Tags: beamer, formatting

A few months ago, I asked for help with formatting curly braces next to bullet points, which worked very well.

However, I have tried to take that code and use it in `beamer`, which is unfortunately telling me it doesn't recognise the `\dimexpr` command, and so I'm having some trouble.

The code I am using is in the link below, can anyone advise me on how to achieve this or something similar in beamer?

[Bullet points and curly braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225579/bullet-points-and-curly-braces/225584#225584)

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The following work for me. Do I miss anything?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Riemann Sum

  \item
  Trapezoidal Rule

  \item
  Simpson's 1/3 Rule
    $\smash{\left.\rule{0pt}{.5\dimexpr3\baselineskip+2\itemsep+2\parskip}\right\}
      \text{\parbox{2in}{Newton Cotes formulae of different degrees}}}$

  \item
  Simpson's 3/8 Rule
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW `beamer` doesn't have any hatred for `\dimexpr` FYI.