# How to put curly brace in front of even number of bullets?

Tags: itemize, braces

I need to put curly braces in front of even number of bullets.
The following post works perfectly for odd number of bullets.

[Bullet points and curly braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225579/bullet-points-and-curly-braces)

how can we modify it to for even number of bullets?

Update:

- Is is possible to have a general solution that adjusts automatically for the number of bullets that we have.
- I am using a \documentclass{beamer}. But this should not matter. I ma putting this piece of information since all posted solutions had \documentclass{article}

Snapshot of my editor(left pannel) and PDF(right panel)

[image]

Comment: provided each one of the bullet points occupies only one line, i'd attach the brace construction to the item just above the middle, and move it lower by `.5\baselineskip + .5\itemsep + .5\parsep`.  probably a bit more complicated, because it has to be put in a box, but that should give a starting point for experimentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Riemann Sum
  \item Trapezoidal Rule 
  \item Simpson's 1/3 Rule
  \item Simpson's 3/8 Rule % 
  \smash{\raisebox{.5\dimexpr3\baselineskip+4\itemsep+2\parskip}{$\left.\rule{0pt}{.5\dimexpr4\baselineskip+3\itemsep+3\parskip}\right\}\text{Newton Cotes formulae of different degrees}$}}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

For `beamer` class, `\linewidth` is much smaller and you need to put the text into a `\parbox` to allow text wrap. Note also that `itemize` environment in beamer is totally different from that in normal classes, so, you may need some manual adjustments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,lmodern}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\insm}{%
\smash{\raisebox{.5\dimexpr3\baselineskip+4\itemsep+2\parskip}{$\left.\rule{0pt}{.5\dimexpr4\baselineskip+3\itemsep+3\parskip}\right\}$\ \parbox{5.5cm}{Newton Cotes formulae of different degrees}}}
}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Riemann Sum 
  \item Trapezoidal Rule 
  \item Simpson's 1/3 Rule
  \item Simpson's 3/8 Rule \insm
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Finally, a flexible `tikz` solution (since I'm personally fond of tikz, I decided to post an alternative beautiful solution with tikz):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,lmodern,calc,tikz,textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\insm{%
$\left.\rule{0pt}{2.5\baselineskip}\right\}$\parbox{\textwidth-2ex}{%
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbullet] Newton Cotes formulae ...
\item[\textbullet] Newton Cotes formulae ...
\end{itemize}}
}    
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Riemann Sum 
  \item Trapezoidal Rule\tikzmark{S}
  \item Simpson's 1/3 Rule\tikzmark{E}
  \item Simpson's 3/8 Rule 
\end{itemize}    
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{%
\node [shift={(1ex,.6ex)},text width=6.5cm,anchor=west] at ($(pic cs:S)!.5!(pic cs:E)$){\insm};}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it is putting the bracket right next to bullets i-e before the text

Comment: @NAASI Make sure you didn't insert an extra `\item` before `\smash{...`. Try first my solution as is, does that error appear?

Comment: I am using a \documentclass{beamer}. Can this be the reason because I just copied your solution in my frame and am getting the same results

Comment: @NAASI That is because the text is longer than the `\textwidth` in beamer.

Comment: how can we fix this?I have added a snapshot of whats going on in my original question

Comment: @NAASI Please see my edit.

Comment: Got it. One last thing. Lets say That I have to write two separate facts (in form of bullets) on right side of bracket. How can we achieve that?

Comment: @NAASI Use the `itemize` environment as usual, and change the triangle to bullet or whatever you like. For example, `\begin{itemize}
  \item[\textbullet] Riemann Sum 
  \item[\textbullet] Trapezoidal Rule 
  \item[\textbullet] Simpson's 1/3 Rule
  \item[\textbullet] Simpson's 3/8 Rule
\end{itemize}`.

Comment: I need to put two facts on right side of bracket i-e 1. Newton blah blah blah 2. John blah blah blah

Comment: @NAASI Yes, put it here : `\parbox{5.5cm}{<HERE>}`. Replace HERE with your two facts.

Answer (score 9):

One option that would work for any kind of elements (`\item` bullets (even or odd number) or whatever), would be to use TikZ and its [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library. Place some marks at the desired locations and then use those marks to draw the brace with its accompanying text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Riemann Sum\tikzmark{start}
  \item
  Trapezoidal Rule
  \item
  Simpson's 1/3 Rule
  \item
  Simpson's 3/8 Rule\tikzmark{end}
\end{itemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=12pt}]
  ([yshift=2ex]{{pic cs:end}|-{pic cs:start}}) --
    node[xshift=15pt,anchor=west] {some test text} 
  ([yshift=-0.5ex]pic cs:end);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting a compiler error related to \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing}. ! I can't find file `tikzlibrarytikzmark.code.tex'.<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex\catcode `\@ =\csname tikz... ...ibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing}

Comment: I think your solution is more flexible but I dont understand why I am getting this error

Comment: @NAASI The error message indicates that your LaTeX system is outdated. Update it and the problem will disappear.

Comment: @NAASI Or search the site for `\tikzmark` implementations; IIRC, it was conceived here.

Answer (score 2):

I propose an environment, `braceditemize` that *simulates* an `itemize` environment, within a `blockarray` environment. It has an optional argument, the text that will be to the right of the brace:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, etoolbox}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\newcommand\tabitem{\ifbool{firstrow}{\relax}{\\[\itemsep]}\boolfalse{firstrow}\makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\textbullet}\hspace*{\labelsep}}
\newbool{firstrow}
\newenvironment{braceditemize}[1][]{%
\booltrue{firstrow}
\vspace*{\topsep}\par\noindent
\setlength\BAextrarowheight{\parsep}\begin{blockarray}{@{}l <{\enspace}\Right{\}}{#1}}}
{\rule[-\itemsep-\parsep]{0pt}{\itemsep + \parsep}\end{blockarray}}

\begin{document}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\begin{braceditemize}[Newton-Cotes formulae of different degrees]
  \tabitem Riemann Sum
  \tabitem Trapezoidal Rule
  \tabitem Simpson's 1/3 Rule
  \tabitem Simpson's 3/8 Rule
\end{braceditemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\begin{itemize}
  \item Riemann Sum

  \item
  Trapezoidal Rule

  \item
  Simpson's 1/3 Rule
    $\smash{\left.\rule{0pt}{.5\dimexpr3\baselineskip+2\itemsep+2\parskip}\right\}
      \text{Newton Cotes formulae of different degrees}}$

  \item
  Simpson's 3/8 Rule
\end{itemize}


\begin{itemize}
  \item Riemann Sum

  \item
  Trapezoidal Rule

  \item
  Simpson's 1/3 Rule
    \smash{\raisebox{.5\dimexpr\baselineskip+\itemsep+\parskip}{%
    $\left.\rule{0pt}{.5\dimexpr4\baselineskip+3\itemsep+3\parskip}\right\}$
      Newton Cotes formulae of different degrees}}

  \item
  Simpson's 3/8 Rule
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```