# Tikz behaviour at page end

Tags: lists, page-breaking, tikzmark

I am using tikz to put braces around an enumerated list as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/259121/how-to-put-curly-brace-in-front-of-even-number-of-bullets?lq=1). I have two curly braces with multiple comments as shown below

[image]

The problem is I am not able to get the braces at the right place when my list is at a page end. The braces appear on the next page at weird positions. Interestingly if I move my list to some other position away from the page end, I get it at the right place. Here is the code

```
 \documentclass[sunil1]{sunil}

  \usepackage{lmodern,calc,tikz,textcomp}
  \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\insm{%
  $\left.\rule{0pt}{1.6\baselineskip}\right\}$\parbox{\textwidth-2ex}{%
  \setlist[1]{itemsep=-5pt}
  \begin{itemize}
   \item[] (\textit{a} to \textit{b})
   \item[]Deformations 
   \item[] (\textit{b} to \textit{c})
  \end{itemize}}
 }    
\newcommand\wnsm{%
  $\left.\rule{0pt}{1.6\baselineskip}\right\}$\parbox{\textwidth-1ex}{%
  \setlist[1]{itemsep=-2pt}
  \begin{itemize}
   \item[] 
   \item[]Rigid-Body Motion
   \item[] (\textit{c} to \textit{d})
  \end{itemize}}
}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item A change in size (extension or contraction)\tikzmark{S}
  \item A change in shape (shear or distortion) \tikzmark{E}
  \item A rigid-body translation\tikzmark{W}
  \item A rigid-body rotation \tikzmark{N}
\end{enumerate}

 \tikz[remember picture, overlay]{%
   \node [shift={(1ex,.6ex)},text width=5.5cm,anchor=west] at ($(pic cs:S)!.5!(pic cs:E)$){\insm};}
 \tikz[remember picture, overlay]{%
   \node [shift={(1ex,.6ex)},text width=5.5cm,anchor=west] at ($(pic cs:W)!.5!(pic cs:N)$){\wnsm};}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where do you want to put braces if items are on different pages?

Comment: No, the items should be on the same page. Just that I want to put the them at ending of a page, but when I do that, the braces appear on the next page at weird positions, floating around inside the text. I want them to be exactly as in the picture.

Comment: Don't put a paragraph break before the `\tikz` commands. You may also need to put them before the end of the `enumerate` environment. The point is you need them to be processed before the page is shipped out.

Comment: @cfr Thanks but that doesn't help.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a standard class? If so, edit your example accordingly. If not, presumably something in the class is implicated and you'd need to provide a link.

Comment: Please don't ask the [same question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299666/curly-braces-around-list-items-with-multiline-comments) twice. It clutters up the site and duplicates effort to no purpose whatsoever. You can always edit a question to add additional information.

Comment: @cfr I have deleted the previous question now. Thanks. The class file I am using can be found here https://cyberaide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/papers/11-greenit-bookch/sunil.cls

Comment: If it helps, the braces and the accompanying text are moving exactly one page further to the next page if I place this code towards a page end.