# How to put one symbol that spawns several itemized lines in Beamer Presentation?

Tags: beamer, symbols, itemize

In Beamer presentation I have itemized block:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item object
    \item type
    \item action
\end{itemize}
```

I was wondering if I could put one symbol - } that will spawn to several lines and then write one description after it. something like this:

[image]

I was looking for it but was not able to find anything similar. So any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: You can use `tikzmark`.

Comment: Does [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/433933/203621) answer your question? Or [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/259121/203621)?

Comment: @Fractal Yes thank you very much, I used one of the answers. I guess I should have searched with braces keyword. Should I delete this question then right?

Comment: No, flag it as duplicate of the one you used.

Comment: @Fractal Ok, I flagged accordingly,  Thanks again.