# Itemize and curly braces at left

Tags: itemize, braces

In the following examples,

- [Bullet points and curly braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225579/bullet-points-and-curly-braces)
- [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text)

how can I put the curly braces at the left side?

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item Riemann Sum
  \item Trapezoidal Rule
  \item
  Simpson's 1/3 Rule
    $\smash{\left.\rule{0pt}{.5\dimexpr3\baselineskip+2\itemsep+2\parskip}\right\}
      \text{Newton Cotes formulae of different degrees}}$
  \item Simpson's 3/8 Rule
\end{itemize}
```

BTW, is there any method which avoids using math mode?

[image: latex curly braces]

I have tried the following which has failed as well:

```
$\left\{\text{
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{itemize}
}\right.$
```

Comment: The solutions with `tikz` avoid math mode, but `tikz` is a big machine too.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, is there any available example?

Comment: tikz code added to answer, but it is not simpler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a `minipage` as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Riemann Sum
\item Newton Cotes formulae of different degrees
  \(
  \left\{ \quad
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\linewidth}
    \item Trapezoidal Rule
    \item Simpson's \( 1/3 \) Rule
    \item Simpson's \( 3/8 \) Rule
    \end{minipage}
  \right.
  \)
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively you can use a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Riemann Sum
\item Newton Cotes formulae of different degrees
  \(
  \left\{
    \begin{tabular}{@{\textbullet\enspace}l}
      Trapezoidal Rule \\
      Simpson's \( 1/3 \) Rule \\
      Simpson's \( 3/8 \) Rule
    \end{tabular}
    \right.
  \)
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

This avoids having to specify the width, but means that you have to provide the `itemize`-like markup yourself.

As Schweinebacke points out there is also the `varwidth` environment from the `varwidth` package, that will replace `minipage` and you just specify a maximum width.  However it behaves slightly differently: the itemize list is now at second level, so by default bullets are replaced by dashes, and there is a considerable left margin indentation.  So if want the same type of appearance as before you need to modify the `itemize` style, e.g. via the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Riemann Sum
\item Newton Cotes formulae of different degrees
  \(
  \left\{
    \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet,leftmargin=1em]
      \item Trapezoidal Rule
      \item Simpson's \( 1/3 \) Rule
      \item Simpson's \( 3/8 \) Rule
      \end{itemize}
    \end{varwidth}
    \right.
  \)
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

If you really want to avoid math mode and use `tikz` then you can use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Riemann Sum
\item Newton Cotes formulae of different degrees
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \node[inner ysep=0pt] (A) at (0,0) {
    \begin{tabular}{@{\textbullet\enspace}l}
      Trapezoidal Rule \\
      Simpson's \( 1/3 \) Rule \\
      Simpson's \( 3/8 \) Rule
    \end{tabular}};
    \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.5em},decorate,thick]
    (A.south west) -- (A.north west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

which is at tabular at heart.  In my opinion, the math mode option is easier.

Comment: is there also a possibility which does not require specifying a width?

Comment: @jakun Try `varwidth` with [`varwidth`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) instead of `minipage`.

Comment: A suggestion: Load the `amsmath` package and wrap the material from `\left\{` thru `\right.` in a `\smash[t]{...}` macro. This will give tighter spacing between the two "outer" itemize entries.

Comment: @Mico Yes, that would give the posters overlapping layout, but would not be appropriate if the previous line is longer.